# To add certain characters at the end of line when the line ends with ":"

Tags: linux, shell

I have a text file which contains two types of entries as below:

```
398/GHJKI:/opt/Check/D1/test_1234
875/GHgbhn:/opt/Check/D1/test_1235
398/ANgbhn:
398/ABNHJ:/opt/Check/D1/test_1237
123/ANgbhn:
```

I want to add NA at the end of line where "/opt/Check/D1/test_1237" does not exist, which means the line ends with ":".

Please let me know how to do this.

I tried doing like this

```
if grep -q "test" "/home/C1.txt"; then
awk '$0=$0"NA"' /home/C1.txt > /home/C2.txt
else
:
fi
```

But this adds NA to each line..I want to add NA to line which ends with ":"

The output should look like:

```
398/GHJKI:/opt/Check/D1/test_1234
875/GHgbhn:/opt/Check/D1/test_1235
398/ANgbhn:NA
398/ABNHJ:/opt/Check/D1/test_1237
123/ANgbhn:NA
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this `sed`:

```
sed 's/:$/&NA/' file
```

```
398/GHJKI:/opt/Check/D1/test_1234
875/GHgbhn:/opt/Check/D1/test_1235
398/ANgbhn:NA
398/ABNHJ:/opt/Check/D1/test_1237
123/ANgbhn:NA
```

Here:

- `:$`: Matches `:` before end of line
- `&NA`: Replaces with original matched string i.e. `:` and `NA`

Comment: thanks it worked.. :)  Can u pls explain why we have to use &?

Comment: Using `&` is not a necessity here. You could use `sed 's/:$/:NA/' file` as well. Using `&` is preferred when you need to use a matched substring from matched pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Try this command:

`sed 's/:$/:NA/' filename`

This will replace the `:` with `:NA` only if the line ends with `:`.

Answer (score 0):

I would have preferred sed answer, as it skips file redirection. but as you asked awk so this is awk way of doing it.

here you need to add NA on check whether line ending with : or not so 
way to do in awk is checking line ends with : (i.e. :$ ) if yes then add NA , next is used to skip next code block.

```
$ awk '/:$/{print $0 "NA"; next} {print $0}'
398/GHJKI:/opt/Check/D1/test_1234
875/GHgbhn:/opt/Check/D1/test_1235
398/ANgbhn:NA
398/ABNHJ:/opt/Check/D1/test_1237
123/ANgbhn:NA
```